# Python. Design. Expanding various functions in identical way

Tags: python, design-patterns, decorator

I have the following setting.
I have 3 functions, draw1, draw2 and draw3.
All of them get as input an image, and some other parameters (**different** parameters for various draws, but the image is always one of the parameters).

For every draw function (let's say draw1), I want to define another function with the following properties:
The parameters are the same as draw1 parameters + boolean parameter called "in_place".
If in_place=True -> draw on the image with draw1 and return the image.
If in_place=False -> make a copy of the image and draw on the copy of the image with draw1 and return the copy of the image.

This "expansion" of draw1 is **identical** to all the draw functions.
How can I do this in clean way?
Decorators can be used here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a factory function that builds these functions from the original. It has to check for the `in_place` keyword argument, decide which target to use for your draw function, and call it (with the original parameters minus `in_place`).

It could be:

```
def extend(draw):
    def extended(img, *args, **kwargs):
        # Default value for 'in_place': False
        # You can change it to True if you prefer
        in_place = kwargs.pop('in_place', False)
        if in_place:
            target = img
        else:
            target = img.copy()
        
        draw(target, *args, **kwargs)
        return target
    
    return extended
```

Some examples of use (I used lists instead of images for clarity):

Our draw functions:

```
def draw1(lst, color):
    lst.extend(['draw1', color])

def draw2(lst, shape, color):
    lst.extend(['draw2', shape, color])
```

We create the extended functions with:

```
extended_draw1 = extend(draw1)
extended_draw2 = extend(draw2)
```

If we call them without `in_place` argument, use the default (here, `False`, we draw on a copy)

```
orig = ['Hello']
out = extended_draw1(orig, 'red')
print(out)
# ['Hello', 'draw1', 'red']
print(orig)
# ['Hello']
```

If in_place is `False`, a modified copy is returned, original unchanged

```
orig = ['Hello']
out = extended_draw1(orig, 'red', in_place=False)  # won't change the original
print(out)
# ['Hello', 'draw1', 'red']
print(orig)
# ['Hello']
```

If in_place is `True`, the original is modified

```
orig = ['Hello']
out = extended_draw1(orig, 'red', in_place=True)  # won't change the original
print(out)
# ['Hello', 'draw1', 'red']
print(orig)
# ['Hello', 'draw1', 'red']
```

Some more, using the second function:

```
print(extended_draw2(orig, 'square', 'blue'))
#['Hello', 'draw1', 'red', 'draw2', 'square', 'blue']
print(orig)
#['Hello', 'draw1', 'red']

print(extended_draw2(orig, 'square', 'blue', in_place=True))
#['Hello', 'draw1', 'red', 'draw2', 'square', 'blue']
print(orig)
#['Hello', 'draw1', 'red', 'draw2', 'square', 'blue']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother from another mother